# ArcGIS GP service source data gets copied despite registered folder

Tags: geoprocessing-service, arcgis-enterprise

I have published a script tool that intersects two shape files as a web tool (geoprocessing service). I tried 4 methods to transmit the input files, which all lead to the files getting copied to the server, although their folder is shared and registered.

**1. method: layer type toolbox parameters:**

```
a = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
b = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

arcpy.analysis.Intersect([a, b], f"{arcpy.env.scratchGDB}\\intersected", "ALL")
arcpy.SetParameter(2, f"{arcpy.env.scratchGDB}\\intersected")
```

**2. method: os fuctions**

```
a = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "RP.shp")
b = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "kachel.shp")
```

**3. method: UNC paths**

```
a = r"\\ServerName\SharedFolder\subfolder\RP.shp"
b = r"\\ServerName\SharedFolder\subfolder\kachel.shp"
```

**4. method: matching with layer name string**

```
a = "shapeA"
b = "shapeB"
```

This [documentation](https://bkggis-tl1.bkg/hosting/help/en/server/11.1/manage-data/windows/making-your-data-accessible-to-arcgis-server.htm#ESRI_SECTION2_5AA7B6E854A341C986B1C2344D7CE9B3) says:

**"If you store source files in shared directories, remember that all data source paths within the resource must also use UNC paths or relative paths."**,

The Folder with the ArGIS Pro Project and the files is shared with the domain account used as admin for the ArcGIS Server machine, and for my local account. It is also registered as a data store, with same path for publisher and server.

[image]

Update: Something still seems to be missing with the sharing permissions for the folder in windows. It works on another machine. Maybe it is the thing with the identical account that has to be logged in on the local machine with the folder to be shared (identical username and password of server account).